# Why does Javascript view while loops with and without curly braces differently? Can while loops without curly braces be nested?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, syntax, nested, curly-braces

I am working on a problem to determine whether a linked list is a Palindrome ([Leetcode 234](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/)). I came across this (way above my level) solution.

```
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    let slow = head, fast = head, prev, temp

    while (fast && fast.next)
        slow = slow.next, fast = fast.next.next
    prev = slow, slow = slow.next, prev.next = null

    while (slow)
        temp = slow.next, slow.next = prev, prev = slow, slow = temp
    fast = head, slow = prev

    while (slow) {
        if (fast.val !== slow.val) return false
        else fast = fast.next, slow = slow.next
    } //i added these curly braces because the solution still works with them
    return true
};
```

I was confused by the lack of curly braces so I added them to see if the loops were nested.

However, when I add curly braces to the second while loop, the code times out and if I add them to the first while loop, some test cases fail.

```
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    let slow = head, fast = head, prev, temp
    while (fast && fast.next) {
        slow = slow.next, fast = fast.next.next
    prev = slow, slow = slow.next, prev.next = null
    }
    while (slow) {
        temp = slow.next, slow.next = prev, prev = slow, slow = temp
    fast = head, slow = prev;
    }
    while (slow) {
        if (fast.val !== slow.val) return false
        else fast = fast.next, slow = slow.next
      }
    return true
};
```

I also tried nesting the third while loop within the second like so,

```
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    let slow = head, fast = head, prev, temp
    while (fast && fast.next) {
        slow = slow.next, fast = fast.next.next
    prev = slow, slow = slow.next, prev.next = null
    }
    while (slow) {
        temp = slow.next, slow.next = prev, prev = slow, slow = temp
    fast = head, slow = prev;
    while (slow) {
        if (fast.val !== slow.val) return false
        else fast = fast.next, slow = slow.next
      }
    }
    return true
};
```

and it still does not run. I have tried every variation of nesting possible with no luck, and I don't even know what to Google so I can understand.

what am I missing here? I am so confused

any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank y'all

Comment: The syntax for a while loop is `while` `(` _Expression_ `)` _Statement_ — see [MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and [the specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-while-statement). The _Statement_ is `temp = slow.next, slow.next = prev, prev = slow, slow = temp`. Why do you think `fast = head, slow = prev` would also be part of the statement? See [Are braces necessary in one-line statements in JavaScript?](/q/4797286/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon never seen code that looks like this before, thought the statement would end with a semicolon, not just a new line. But thank u for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you found is not "above your level" at all. On the contrary it is so bad that am not surprised if anyone found it confusing, let alone a beginner. The trick the original code uses, sadly, is to convert multiple statements into  single inline statements using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) so as to avoid typing curly braces, and  leaving out semicolon terminators to save space.

Here's how a *maintenance* programmer might have written it by mechanistically

- replacing comma operator statements with block statements,
- inserting statement terminators,
- moving `temp` to the only block that uses it, and
- not putting an "else" keyword after a conditional `return` statement:

```js
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    let slow = head, fast = head, prev;

    while (fast && fast.next) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    prev = slow;
    slow = slow.next;
    prev.next = null;
    while (slow) {
        let temp = slow.next;
        slow.next = prev;
        prev = slow;
        slow = temp;
    }
    fast = head;
    slow = prev;
    while (slow) {
        if (fast.val !== slow.val) {
            return false;
        }
        fast = fast.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    return true;
};
```

I am not commenting on whether the code works or not, but written this way, inserting curly braces to find out if any of the while loops is nested is *unnecessary*.

---

**Title Questions**

1. Why does JavaScript view `while` loops with and without curly braces differently? It doesn't make such a distinction. The compiler is looking for a statement after `while`, and curly braces and code within them are parsed as a single block statement.
2. Can `while` loops without curly braces be nested? Yes, but not usually (as in "never") as an inline statement immediately after the outer `while`:

   ```
    while(condition1) while(condition2){ code }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is how I was taught to write code. Everyone in the comments was praising them and I couldn't figure out what was going on! lol